# what is "ID" attribute exactly is used for in OData

Tags: c#, odata, wcf-data-services

I wanted to ask what is "`<d:ID>`" attribute exactly is used for in OData ?

I have attached sample service where "ID" (it is defined as entity key") is present.(see code block below)

We have nested entries in response xml like here Product & Categories. Product contains Categories (see code block below)

Example: 
Let say I have 1st Product "TV" which comes under 2 different Categories "Electrical" "ID=1" & "electronics" "ID=2" ...2nd Product "Milk" which comes under Categories "Beverages" "ID=1" & "drink" "ID=5" and I am getting all this data in same response.

Here if you see in example "Electrical" & "Beverages" have same ID( which is 1) but they are present inside different products. Is this case is possible ?

Code Block:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    - <feed xml:base="http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products</id> 
      <title type="text">Products</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
      <link rel="self" title="Products" href="Products" /> 
    - <entry>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)</id> 
      <category term="ODataDemo.Product" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
      <link rel="edit" title="Product" href="Products(0)" /> 
    - <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Categories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Categories" href="Products(0)/Categories">
    - <m:inline>
    - <feed>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Categories</id> 
      <title type="text">Categories</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
      <link rel="self" title="Categories" href="Products(0)/Categories" /> 
    - <entry>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)</id> 
      <category term="ODataDemo.Category" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
      <link rel="edit" title="Category" href="Categories(0)" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Products" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Products" href="Categories(0)/Products" /> 
      <title type="text">Food</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
    - <author>
      <name /> 
      </author>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Products" type="application/xml" title="Products" href="Categories(0)/$links/Products" /> 
    - <content type="application/xml">
    - <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ID> 
      <d:Name>Food</d:Name> 
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
      </feed>
      </m:inline>
      </link>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Supplier" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Supplier" href="Products(0)/Supplier" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ProductDetail" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ProductDetail" href="Products(0)/ProductDetail" /> 
      <title type="text">Bread</title> 
      <summary type="text">Whole grain bread</summary> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
    - <author>
      <name /> 
      </author>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Categories" type="application/xml" title="Categories" href="Products(0)/$links/Categories" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Supplier" type="application/xml" title="Supplier" href="Products(0)/$links/Supplier" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/ProductDetail" type="application/xml" title="ProductDetail" href="Products(0)/$links/ProductDetail" /> 
    - <content type="application/xml">
    - <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ID> 
      <d:ReleaseDate m:type="Edm.DateTimeOffset">1992-01-01T00:00:00Z</d:ReleaseDate> 
      <d:DiscontinuedDate m:null="true" /> 
      <d:Rating m:type="Edm.Int16">4</d:Rating> 
      <d:Price m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:Price> 
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
    - <entry>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products(1)</id> 
      <category term="ODataDemo.Product" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
      <link rel="edit" title="Product" href="Products(1)" /> 
    - <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Categories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Categories" href="Products(1)/Categories">
    - <m:inline>
    - <feed>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products(1)/Categories</id> 
      <title type="text">Categories</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
      <link rel="self" title="Categories" href="Products(1)/Categories" /> 
    - <entry>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)</id> 
      <category term="ODataDemo.Category" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
      <link rel="edit" title="Category" href="Categories(0)" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Products" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Products" href="Categories(0)/Products" /> 
      <title type="text">Food</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
    - <author>
      <name /> 
      </author>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Products" type="application/xml" title="Products" href="Categories(0)/$links/Products" /> 
    - <content type="application/xml">
    - <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ID> 
      <d:Name>Food</d:Name> 
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
    - <entry>
      <id>http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)</id> 
      <category term="ODataDemo.Category" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
      <link rel="edit" title="Category" href="Categories(1)" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Products" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Products" href="Categories(1)/Products" /> 
      <title type="text">Beverages</title> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
    - <author>
      <name /> 
      </author>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Products" type="application/xml" title="Products" href="Categories(1)/$links/Products" /> 
    - <content type="application/xml">
    - <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID> 
      <d:Name>Beverages</d:Name> 
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
      </feed>
      </m:inline>
      </link>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Supplier" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Supplier" href="Products(1)/Supplier" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ProductDetail" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ProductDetail" href="Products(1)/ProductDetail" /> 
      <title type="text">Milk</title> 
      <summary type="text">Low fat milk</summary> 
      <updated>2014-01-07T15:47:23Z</updated> 
    - <author>
      <name /> 
      </author>
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Categories" type="application/xml" title="Categories" href="Products(1)/$links/Categories" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/Supplier" type="application/xml" title="Supplier" href="Products(1)/$links/Supplier" /> 
      <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/relatedlinks/ProductDetail" type="application/xml" title="ProductDetail" href="Products(1)/$links/ProductDetail" /> 
    - <content type="application/xml">
    - <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID> 
      <d:ReleaseDate m:type="Edm.DateTimeOffset">1995-10-01T00:00:00Z</d:ReleaseDate> 
      <d:DiscontinuedDate m:null="true" /> 
      <d:Rating m:type="Edm.Int16">3</d:Rating> 
      <d:Price m:type="Edm.Double">3.5</d:Price> 
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
    </feed>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `<id>` element or the `<d:ID>` element?

Comment: <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ID>  element

Comment: In OData specification it is mentioned "The entity key of an entity type is formed from a subset of primitive properties (e.g. CustomerId, OrderId,LineId`, etc.) of the entity type. The entity key value uniquely identifies an entity within a collection of entities"

Comment: Every **Category** Entity ("Electrical", "Beverage", "Drink", "Electronics", etc.) must have a unique Key. According to the schema _ID_ is the Entity's Key, therefore every Category must have a unique value for _ID_. Every **Product** refers to the same list of Categories, so the Category _IDs_ must still be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ID* is just another attribute belonging to the entity **Product** as defined by [the service's schema](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/%24metadata). Like Product's other attributes defined in the schema (*Name*, *Description*, *ReleaseDate*, etc.) there isn't a guarantee of uniqueness, unless the attribute is also defined as the entity's Key. In this case *ID* is in fact Product's Key, so we know *ID* will be unique for all Product entities.

In the same schema the **Category** entity also has a property *ID*, which serves as that entity's Key. This means that each Product will have an *ID* value unique among all Products, and each Category will have an *ID* value unique among all Categories.

To illustrate this a bit better, try this query out at [the OData API explorer](http://services.odata.org/ODataAPIExplorer/ODataAPIExplorer.html) to show the Categories belonging to each Product:
`http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$expand=Categories`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks for answering my first question..."what is "ID". I have updated my question for second part. Can you please throw some light on it.